# Creating Backbone application

Tags: backbone.js

I am creating a single page application using backbone.js.
My scenario is to render three different layouts in the same page on clicking three different clicks.,,should I create three render functions for these click events in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create three different render methods, but it would probably make more sense to make a different view for each page.  You can then hook each of those views up to separate routes to get three (pseudo-) pages.

Comment: Hi, thanks.. I will try that.. so in case of router, I need to give id as routes.. but in case these three different views include user inputs and button then I need to create models and collections for them.. right? Actually I'm a beginner in backbone..  .. thanks

Comment: So in this case,I need to create routes .. if I have three views,  I should  create three id for each view to be rendered..

Comment: Yes, although Backbone calls them "routes", not IDs (unlike a fixed ID, the routes can be defined as regular expressions that match patterns and not just fixed strings).

Comment: Thanks.. can you please explain the flow for this.. I mean I have one index. Html or the home page of the user.. in this home page, I have two panels..on clicking on a link, a view will be rendered....

Comment: I have created templates for the views .. but what will be the flow.. I'm little bit confused..